# PowerShell - Get unique rows based on multiple columns from multiple tab/CSV delimited files by passing arguments to Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to club multiple tab delimited files from a folder & get a unique result of distinct columns.

I have been able to make it work by passing the list of columns for the unique rows directly  to `Select-Object` command.

However, I want to parameterise the unique columns list & pass it as a command argument because I am trying to create a function for this & expect the consumer to pass these values.

I have tried the below but it is not working & does not return any values.

```
$FileDate="20200420"
$TempFilePath="C:\Abdul\Work\Work From Home\TempFiles"
$DistinctColumnList="'ColA','ColB','ColC'"
   
$FilePattern =  $FileDate + "*.SDE"

$FinalFileNamePath = "C:\Abdul\Work\Work From Home\TempOut" + "\" + $FileDate + "_Combined.csv" 
$data = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t"  -Path  (Get-ChildItem -Path $TempFilePath -Filter $FilePattern).FullName   

#This Works!!
#$dataUnique =$data | Select-Object 'ColA','ColB','ColC' -Unique

#How do I make this work?
$dataUnique =$data | Select-Object $DistinctColumnList -Unique


$dataUnique | export-csv $FinalFileNamePath -notypeinformation

$Waits = Read-Host -Prompt 'Finished'
```

Comment: `$DistinctColumnList="'ColA','ColB','ColC'"` --> `$DistinctColumnList = 'ColA','ColB','ColC'`  and `$dataUnique =$dataUnique | Select-Object ...` --> `$dataUnique = $data | Select-Object ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. Just convert that string to an Array & use it.

```
$DistinctColumnList="ColA,ColB,ColC"
$ColumnsListArray=$DistinctColumnList -Split ",";

$dataUnique =$data | Select-Object $ColumnsListArray -Unique
```

Comment: Why make it a single string in the first place? Just take off the double quotes and use `$DistinctColumnList = 'ColA','ColB','ColC'`, so it will be a string array. Also, you are still selecting from the wrong variable, since the data is in `$data`, not `$dataUnique`

Comment: @Theo $data was a typo.corrected it even in qn. Thanks for identifying. I cannot directly create $DistinctColumnList as array because I am expecting that to be passed via command arguments.

Comment: Arrays can be passed as parameter just fine.. `Param ( [string[]]$DistinctColumnList)` for instance